# Inkscape on OSX copies rasterized images from SVG

Tags: x11

I'm trying to copy an object out of an SVG file using inkscape, however when I paste it back in to a new inkscape file it's no longer the svg version, but a rasterized version.
I'm not sure if it's because inkscape runs in XQuartz and the clipboard is behaving odly.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

[Here](http://mandarapte.com/apple/copy-pasting-vector-objects-svg-file-vector-svg-file-inkscape-converts-bitmap-working-pasteboards-x11/) someone had the same problem.
They solved it by turning off X11's Pasteboard Syncing:

> Disabling ‘Sync PasteBoard’ Functionality within X11 (Which is
>   Included in XQuartz App for OSX Mountain Lion) solves the problem of
>   converting vector object to Bitmap after pasting the same object in
>   another SVG file.
>
> Do This (Go to): X11 > Click on ‘Preferences’ tab > Choose
>   ‘Pasteboard’ tab > Uncheck ‘Enable Syncing’

Answer (score 4):

I solved this problem by *importing* another svg file into the current one.

File --> Import... --> Select "All Vectors" (or "*.svg") in the filter selection menu.

This copies the entire content of the imported file into the current one in vector format.

Answer (score 0):

This is not really a solution but a workaround I learned from [this page](https://dawes.wordpress.com/2015/10/19/inkscape-clipboard-fix-on-mac/) and it requires you to flex those muscle memory of <kbd>Command</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> and then <kbd>Command</kbd><kbd>V</kbd>.
The workaround is to use <kbd>Control</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> to duplicate instead of copy and pasting. Off course this does not work if you want to copy from one file to another or in/out of Inkscape.

(It is a shame that Inkscape developers are ignoring all mac users. Looking forwards to see a real native implementation away from crappy X11!)